# Как вывести данные JSON (получаемые по ссылке) на сайт с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, json, parse

У меня есть ссылка - при переходе по ней открывается огромный JSON объект (там много разных фильмов).
Необходимо вывести эти фильмы в виде карточек на сайт, уже второй день ищу и не могу найти ничего про это(((
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать или что почитать?

Нужно сделать пустой объект в файле js и распарсить как-то туда этот JSON методом parse, я так понимаю, но не знаю, как написать(

Вот код, но он бесполезен:

```js
// const cardFilm = {
//   poster: '',
//   year: '',
//   duration: '',
//   genre: '',
//   producer: '',
//   actors: '',
//   divdescription: ''
// }

let filmCard = {}
```

```html
<div class="film-card" id="filmCard">
    <!-- <div class="poster"></div>
    <div class="name"></div>
    <div class="year"></div>
    <div class="duration"></div>
    <div class="genre"></div>
    <div class="producer"></div>
    <div class="actors"></div>
    <div class="description"></div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: `fetch('ссылка на json файл').then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Большое спасибо! Я установила для этого решения fetch api расширение, но теперь он выдает такую ошибку: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Я прочла, что это можно исправить, добавив в файл package.json - type: module, но у меня в проекте такого файла нет, он должен был быть создан автоматически node.js ведь? Или как его еще можно создать, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: А вы используете NodeJS?

Comment: Нет, тут пока есть только html, css и js файлы)

Comment: `Я установила для этого решения fetch api расширение` зачем? fetch это браузерная "штучка".